# unlock phone displays recent apps list

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

I am trying to build a custom launcher for android (using Android 6.0). After using the launcher and unlocking the phone, I get the recent apps list (overview screen) displayed instead of the launcher.

How can I change this behavior to instantly display the homescreen/launcher after unlocking [NullLauncher](https://github.com/notriddle/null-launcher)

the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Home"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But it gives me the same result: after i unlock the screen it displays the recent apps list.[image: Recent apps list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code and try once..

```
<activity android:name=".Home"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for!